# How can I force a form to submit using JavaScript when a person hits the space bar in the input field?

Tags: javascript

Is that possible?  Google searches are leading me nowhere.

My Sample form:

```
<form action="search.asp" method="post" name="form1">

    User ID <input type="text" size="15" name="userid"><p>
    Last Name <input type="text" size="15" name="lastname"><p>
    School <input type="text" size="15" name="school"><p>
    District <input type="text" size="15" name="district"><p>
    Email <input type="text" size="20" name="email"><p>

    <input type="submit" value=" Go Search! ">

</form>
```

This needs to work from any input box on the form.  I tried onkeyUP but wouldn't work or I probably wrote it wrong.  I am no javascript expert.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to make some sort of auto-complete functionality? If not, why submit on space bar? In the above example there's all kinds of valid locations for a spacebar to be entered without intending a submit. I'm just trying to get some context here.

Comment: What if the school's name has two words?

Comment: What if the last name is *van der Sar* or *da Silva* or something?

Comment: I am just going to search for the first word entered and match the results accordingly.  It is a very small database so the results will be limited.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you'd do this, but in Firefox, you would write:

```
<form action="search.asp" method="post" name="form1" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 32) this.submit(); return false;">
```

Check here to see how to [retrieve other browsers' key codes](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

Again, this is how you *would* do it, but I think it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I needed.  It is for a personal project and will not be used by anyone else.

I just tried adding the code but now I can't type anything into the form at all.

Comment: It works now if you change it to onkeyup instead of onkeydown.  I have no idea why, I am just glad it works.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The whole form to submit whenever a space is detected by may be a little messy, but what's interesting is to do it for a specific input. I used it in a field where user gives some tags. Each tag must de only one word,and so the space character can be used as an event to store the given tag and wait for the next.

```
<input type="text" id="tagtextbox" onKeyUp="if(event.keyCode == 32) myfunction();" />
```